# Is there a Java Stream method equivalent to Scala's collections "collect"?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Scala's collection provides a method called `collect` that merges `filter` and `map` into a single method. It's particularly useful when filtering an `Object` collection to produce a subset of that collection containing only a particular type.

Is there any such thing with Java 8's Stream?

Comment: I suppose you already know that you can do the right thing by chaining `map`, `filter` and `collect` calls. So what’s the purpose of your request to do that in one method call? Because that “feels” like being more efficient?

Comment: @Holger It ties the pre-condition to the mapping function, which helps make clear one _is_ a pre-condition to the other, as well make it impossible to break the code by changing the order of the method calls.

Comment: Actually, it’s the opposite. No-one can tell from a single method’s signature containing a mapping function and a predicate which is applied first. In contrast, with the `Stream` API, everyone understands the difference between `map(…).filter(…).collect(…)` and `.filter(…).map(…).collect(…)`. And is even able to deduce the meaning of other combinations like `map(…).filter(…).map(…).collect(…)`…

Comment: @Holger Actually, given parameters T -> Boolean and T -> R, for input Stream[T] and output Stream[R], there are only two logical implementations without side effects, and in both of them T -> Boolean comes first.

Comment: You can say the same about combining `map` and `filter`; the order can be deduced from the generic type signature, however, the difference is that for the method chain you can recognize the order intuitively even without knowing the signatures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having a combination of `filter` and `map` in one step is not that useful in Java given its type system. E.g. there is no such `PartialFunction` type.

The closest thing is `flatMap`:

```
List<Object> list=Arrays.asList(0, "foo", 0L, 42.0, true, "false");
List<String> sList = list.stream()
  .flatMap(o-> o instanceof String? Stream.of((String)o): Stream.empty())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(sList);
```

but the expressiveness of

```
.flatMap(o-> o instanceof String? Stream.of((String)o): Stream.empty())
```

is not that bigger compared to

```
.filter(o -> o instanceof String).map(o -> (String)o)
```

Of course, you may create a helper method encapsulating these steps in a single, undissolvable operation:

```
static <T> Stream<T> onlyType(Stream<?> s, Class<T> type) {
    return s.filter(type::isInstance).map(type::cast);
}
```

then you can use it like

```
List<String> sList=onlyType(list.stream(), String.class).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to provide the answer of your question as I read somewhere -

```
<R,A> R collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)
```

R - the type of the result
A - the intermediate accumulation type of the Collector
collector - the Collector describing the reduction
Returns - the result of the reduction

Performs a mutable reduction operation on the elements of this stream using a Collector. A Collector encapsulates the functions used as arguments to collect(Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer), allowing for reuse of collection strategies and composition of collect operations such as multiple-level grouping or partitioning. 
If the stream is parallel, and the Collector is concurrent, and either the stream is unordered or the collector is unordered, then a concurrent reduction will be performed (see Collector for details on concurrent reduction.)

This is a terminal operation.

When executed in parallel, multiple intermediate results may be instantiated, populated, and merged so as to maintain isolation of mutable data structures. Therefore, even when executed in parallel with non-thread-safe data structures (such as ArrayList), no additional synchronization is needed for a parallel reduction.

The following will accumulate strings into an ArrayList:

```
List<String> asList = stringStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The following will classify Person objects by state and city, cascading two Collectors together:

```
 Map<String, Map<String, List<Person>>> peopleByStateAndCity
     = personStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getState,
                                                  Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity)));
```

Comment: I'm not talking about Java 8's `Stream`'s `collect` method. I'm talking about Scala's `collect` method and asking for an equivalent in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the `Stream` interface and some of the supporting libraries, there isn't a **single** operation that does both of these and produces an output `Stream` (based on my short reading of the Scala `collect` method).

You would need to apply both functions to a `Stream` to get the desired output `Stream` which can then be collected or any other functions you want to apply to it.

```
collection.stream()
  .filter(predicateFunction)
  .map(mappingFunction)
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: That *is* a single operation, but that operation is prepared using chained method invocations which is just raising the flexibility of the API.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the Scala documentation, `collect` filters based on whether the function is present, and applies the function to each qualifying object.  A Java class has a fixed definition, so such a test wouldn't make much sense.  The closest analog would be testing for an interface and invoking its method (the function) in multiple steps:

```
stream.filter(e -> e instanceof SomeInterface).map(SomeInterface.class::cast).map(AnotherClass::convertSomeInterfaceToSomethingElse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
tList.stream().map[E](func).collect(Collectors.toList[E])
```

The tList is a type of you source list,and E is a type you want returned.If the source type is same as returned type,the [E] is not necessary in mapE,seem to the map func in scala returned type is object.