# Java 8 Stream API : Filter on instance, and cast

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of objects:

```
List<SomeType> myList;
```

I want to get a list of sub-types available in this list:

```
List<SomeChildType> myChildList = myList.stream().filter(e -> e instanceof SomeChildType).collect(??????)
```

I don't know how to collect to obtain the correct list type.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27559231/2711488

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242103/how-to-reuse-application-of-filter-map-on-a-stream

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You need to cast the objects:

```
List<SomeChildType> myChildList = myList.stream()
                                        .filter(SomeChildType.class::isInstance)
                                        .map(SomeChildType.class::cast)
                                        .collect(toList())
```

Comment: I recommend a consistent style. Either `.filter(e -> e instanceof SomeChildType).map(e -> (SomeChildType)e)` or `.filter(SomeChildType.class::isInstance).map(SomeChildType.class::cast)`

Comment: @Holger I hadn't thought of `Class::isInstance` - thanks.

Comment: `.map(SomeChildType.class::cast)` does not work for me. Any further stream function like `.filter()` wants me to cast the item again and if not the compiler tells me symbol could not be found

Comment: @xetra11 It compiles fine: http://ideone.com/SBk97H - did you include the static import for `toList`?

Comment: This is super extra cool!

Comment: This is a really neat functional solution. Good work.

Comment: In IDEA and Java8, it still prompts me to cast the result to List<SomeChildType> explicitly, anyone knows why?

Comment: @K.Symbol I just tested it with intellij and it works as expected. You can maybe create a separate question with your code?

Comment: @assylias Ok, I have posted my question and screenshot here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453941/need-to-cast-the-list-again-after-already-filtering-and-casting-objects-with-jav

Comment: We really need a filterMap in java where you provide a lamda that transforms the stream and filters it simultaneously. The signature would be Function<T, Optional<U>> where T is the input and U is the filtered and transformed output.

Comment: With this code, I get `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: SomeType.isInstance() is applicable for argument types: SomeOtherType`. `.filter(e -> e instanceof SomeChildType).map(e -> (SomeChildType)e)` works properly.