# Need to cast the list again after already filtering and casting objects with Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-stream

I have a list of objects, and I want to filter out those objects of a specific type, cast and collect them into a new list. That's why I use the stream API suggested in the following questions:

[Java 8 Stream API : Filter on instance, and cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879086/java-8-stream-api-filter-on-instance-and-cast)

[Is it possible to cast a Stream in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511750/is-it-possible-to-cast-a-stream-in-java-8)

However, Intellij tells me that I have to cast the collected list again after filtering&casting&collecting, I want to figure out why? And, if I accept the suggestion, the error goes away, but is that the right way to do it?

[image]

Background: I am developing a static program analysis with Eclipse JDT, so I am overwriting the visit() methods to process AST nodes with specific type.

Here is my code processing the AnnotationTypeDeclaration:

```java
  @Override
  public boolean visit(AnnotationTypeDeclaration node) {
    List<AnnotationTypeMemberDeclaration> memberDeclarations = (List<AnnotationTypeMemberDeclaration>) node.bodyDeclarations().stream()
            .filter(AnnotationTypeMemberDeclaration.class::isInstance)
            .map(AnnotationTypeMemberDeclaration.class::cast)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // ... do something with the memberDeclarations
    return true;
}
```

Here is the definition of annotationTypeDeclaration.bodyDeclarations():

```java
    public List bodyDeclarations() {
        return this.bodyDeclarations;
    }
```

Comment: do you by any chance have differrent package `import` for the same class? what is the type of `node.bodyDeclarations`? (and do not share images for code)

Comment: Can you post the code as code so it's possible to copy paste it? And can you give a complete example (for example: what is the type of `node`?).

Comment: I have appended related background and code, hope that helps!

Comment: The problem is that `public List bodyDeclarations()` returns a [*raw type*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: Will it help if bodyDeclarations() starts returning List< AnnotationTypeMemberDeclaration>, not the rawtype as was correctly mentioned?

Comment: The bodyDeclarations() is from a library jar, so I am afraid that I cannot change its return type.

Comment: Then use `((List<?>)node.bodyDeclarations()).stream()` as the starting point of the stream operation. The cast will not issue any warning as you are denoting that the list element type is unknown, but the subsequent operations are not using raw types anymore, so the `.map(AnnotationTypeMemberDeclaration.class::cast)` will have the desired effect.